# get all uppercase " words " from a text

Tags: php, regex, uppercase, lowercase

I want to get all uppercase string from a text using regex and PHP, for example in this sentence " `Hello FROM USA Tô ENGLAND` "

I want to get those words " `FROM USA ENGLAND` ", which means the word must have uppercase characters (all the characters) not only one.

I try to use this regex but without any solution

```
preg_match_all('/\b([A-Z]+)\b/', $text, $matches);
```

Comment: How does it not work for you?  https://3v4l.org/9kjmF

Comment: you can use this sentence `Hello FROM USA Tô ENGLAND` you will get T

Comment: Use u flag: `/\b([A-Z]+)\b/u` https://3v4l.org/DKCVC

Comment: Please ensure in future that original question has the code that led you to ask in first place :)

Comment: Duplicate of [PHP word boundary /b regex not working with French](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45661590/8967612).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it's what do you need:

```
$text = 'Hello FROM USA to ENGLAND';
preg_match_all('/\b([A-Z]+)\b/u', $text, $matches);
print(implode(' ', $matches[0]));
```

Output:

```
FROM USA ENGLAND
```

You forgot to use `implode` function for the get `string` also you need only first result in `$matches`.

Comment: When writing an answer, you should also write an explanation what you've changed and why. Specially when the change is only a few characters.