# Regex Python french accent

Tags: python, regex

I use this code: `b = re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+', ' ', a)`. Nevertheless i need to take account of the french accents: `àâéèêëïîôùûç`. Can you please help me? :)

Thanks.

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922097/regular-expression-for-french-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex for accented characters has [been covered before really well over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690499/concrete-javascript-regex-for-accented-characters-diacritics).

If you're dealing with French accents (not umlauts etc) then you're code could be updated like this:

```
b = re.sub('[^A-zÀ-ú]+', ' ', a)
```

That should amend your previous "all upper and lower case letters" to "all upper and lower case letters including accents"

Comment: `À-ú` matches much more than french accented character. And doesn't mach lowercase. `A-z` matches more tan just letters. Have a look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're like to replace all the letters, taking into account unicode, do the following:

```
text = "àâéèêëïîôùûç"
re.sub('\w+', ' ', text, re.UNICODE)
```

Please note that the `re.UNICODE` is not needed in python3, as it does unicode matching by default.

Comment: FYI: always use `flags=`, `count=` etc explicitly as the positions change between different functions. For ex: `sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)` and `findall(pattern, string, flags=0)` ... so, your code is actually doing `count=re.UNICODE`