# How to write preg_match for english and french charaters?

Tags: laravel

This is my `LangRule` file

```
<?php

namespace Modules\Newsletter\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class LangRule implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
       

       return preg_match("/[^a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ.\-'_]*$/",$value);
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'Please select either English or French as your input language';
    }
}
```

I want to match English,French and `.'-_` from input.
My preg_match is not taking French characters.
Can anyone help how I can do that. Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [unicode properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html):

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-ZàâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇ]+$/", $string);
```

Comment: But I only want English and French.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922097/regular-expression-for-french-characters

Comment: when I am using this regex:/^[a-zA-ZÀ-Ÿ]*$/
and using one of my field as french chracter is giving invalid format@sta

Comment: Would be like `regex:/^[a-zA-ZàâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇ]*$/`

Comment: please also guide me for special chracters.

Comment: For Special character `preg_match('/[#$%^&*()+=\-\[\]\';,.\/{}|":<>?~\\\\]/', $string);`

Comment: For special characters `preg_match('/[#$%^&*()+=\-\[\]\';,.\/{}|":<>?~\\\\]/', $string);`