# French special characters unicode required for first name

Tags: javascript, unicode, wcs

In the project that i am working on i want to add enhancement feature where user can add their French name in the first name field.

I want to include all the special characters for French

Right now in the current code, when I am trying to add French characters in the First name, an error is getting thrown.

[image]

Please find below JS code validation for First Name. Which exists in the code right now.

```
var firstNameRegex  = /^[a-zA-Z\u3000\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FFF\-\'\s]{1,45}$/;
```

I tried for 5 special characters like this

```
var firstNameRegex  = /^[a-zA-Z\.\u3000\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FFF\u0105\u0107\u0119\u0142\u0144\u00f3\u015b\u017a\u017c\-\'\s]{1,45}$/;
```

But to include all the characters unicode separately seems bit lengthy
Does anyone has any idea how to include all the French Characters with an simpler code.

I tried this combination

```
        var firstNameRegex  = /^[a-zA-Z\u3000\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FFF\u00C0-\u017F\-\'\s]{1,45}$/;
```

But this is not working

Comment: When i am adding French characters in the text field i am now getting invalid characters error

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922097/regular-expression-for-french-characters

Comment: Obligatory: https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score -1):

Since you’re a dual-language developer I suggest you get stuck into all JS functions that start with “**.locale**” or "**.toLocal**"

Taking advantage of these functions can help you with dates, strings, numbers, currencies, etc, in non-English languages.

Here's an example with strings... (or French names if you prefer)

```
const a = 'réservé'; // With accents, lowercase

const b = 'RESERVE'; // No accents, uppercase


console.log(a.localeCompare(b));

// Expected output: 1


console.log(a.localeCompare(b,'en', { sensitivity: 'base' }));

// Expected output: 0
```

This example and further reading on the matter, comes from...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare

Non-English language *form validation* should embrace such functions instead of regex() and such.

Comment: I'm just curious, how do you get the value of `b`? I mean when validating a form, the user input (`a`) could be anything ...

Comment: Like many, I use .localeCompare() predominantly in string sorting so I have some basic understanding of internationalization; as a non-dual language developer… but I think the link I posted may answer your question.

Answer (score -2):

you can modify regex-

```
  var firstNameRegex  = /^[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F\.\u3000\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FFF\-\'\s]{1,45}$/;
```

### hope this workd

Comment: Can you please explain this Unicode.

Comment: \u00C0-\u00FF - This range cover  Latin-1 Supplement block  It includes characters like À, Á, Â, Ã, Ä, Å, Æ...., \u0100-\u017F -  Latin Extended-A block like Ā, Ă, Ą, Ć, Ĉ, Ċ, Č... , \u0180-\u024F - Latin Extended-B block ƀ, Ɓ, Ƃ, ƃ, Ƅ, ƅ, Ɔ, Ƈ, ƈ, Ɖ... , \u1E00-\u1EFF - Latin Extended Additional block  like Ḁ, ḁ, Ḃ, ḃ, Ḅ, ḅ, Ḇ, ḇ, Ḉ, ḉ, Ḋ, and more

Comment: Please update the answer instead of posting code in a comment

Comment: Does this change the existing functionality of the code

Comment: Its not working for French characters

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922097/regular-expression-for-french-characters   review this